# Creating cookies by calling PHP website from Node API

Tags: php, node.js, cookies

We have our current website in PHP. We are currently upgrading it in Node. We will upgrade it step by step so we'll have some pages in PHP and some other in Node.
Problem is, when users will connect we have to make sure they have a session in both PHP and Node, so they won't have to connect twice.

In PHP we create a PHPSESSID cookie and we store all the data in a session file in /tmp.
In Node we use a JWT token.

What i am trying to achieve right now is: when and user connects with a page that runs on Node, it has to create a PHPSESSID cookie and the session file, so when he will navigate to another page that runs on PHP he will still be connected.

The PHP website and the Node API have the same domain but run on a different port.

Right now what my code does is:

- I call the signIn function from the Node API
- It creates the JWT token and the user is connected properly in Node
- I call the PHP website like this: http://www.mysite.local/ajax/login?user=user&pass=pwd
- It creates the session file correctly
- It creates the PHPSESSID cookie

But when i check the cookies of my domain, the PHPSESSID doesn't appear. But it does after i create it and print $_COOKIE in PHP.
And because of that PHP can't find any PHPSESSID cookie and can't access the session file.

I'm using Node with GraphQL and Apollo, and PHP with Zend Framework 1.12

Here is how i call PHP with Node:

```
const url = `http://www.mysite.local/ajax/login?email=${data.email}&password=${data.password}`
const headers = {
  Referer: 'http://www.mysite.local/auth'
}
await fetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers: headers })
```

The sessions in PHP are managed by Zend

I'm testing on Firefox.

Comment: "I call the PHP website like this" — Well. That's JavaScript. Is it browser-side JavaScript or Node-side JavaScript?

Comment: As @Quentin points out, it would be useful to know what runtime is running the proposed javascript code.

In anyways, I would have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#extract-set-cookie-header. For debugging, it could be useful at least see if the cookie is being retrieved from the http request.

Comment: @Quentin it's Node-side JavaScript

Comment: @MomoKebab – The *browser* isn't going to store the cookie if you make the request from Node.

Comment: @Quentin - Why? Is there another way to do it? When i try to access cookies from Node it works, i got the same result with PHP. So why couldn't it work if i request it from Node?

Comment: @MomoKebab — For the same reason that if you (the browser) ask your friend (Node.js) to dip their hand in a bucket of paint **your** hand doesn't change colour.

Comment: @Quentin - I'm not sure if you understood what i'm trying to do, or maybe i'm the one not comprehending. But what i'm trying to do is Node asks PHP to create a cookie but PHP doesn't do it, or maybe he does but it doesn't appear in the cookie list of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP cookies work like this:

1. The client sends an HTTP request to the server
2. The server responds with an HTTP response which includes a `Set-Cookie` header
3. The client then stores the cookie

Later on, the client sends another HTTP request to the same server. Since it has a stored cookie, the cookie is including in the request headers.

---

Browsers will, in general, automatically store cookies. (There are some edge cases, like Ajax requests only handling cookies in cross-origin requests if [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) is enabled).

Server-side code will, in general, not automatically store cookies. When dealing with server-side code you usually need to explicitly deal with cookies, usually by configuring a cookie jar library (e.g. [`fetch-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-cookie)).

---

1. You are making an HTTP request from the browser to Node.js.
2. Node.js is making an HTTP request to PHP.
3. PHP is responding with a cookie (I assume)
4. Node.js is ignoring the cookie
5. Node.js is making an HTTP response to the browser
6. The browser gets the HTTP response (with no `Set-Cookie` header in it).

At no point does Node.js either read the cookie from the request it made to PHP or copy that cookie in the response it makes to the browser.

That is what you need to do.

(And then you'll need to continue to proxy requests to the PHP through the Node.js because the cookie stored in the browser would be associated with the Node.js server).

Comment: Wow thanks, i didn't knew the exact process to create cookies. I have a much better understanding of what i'm doing now. I was actually currently reading the response from PHP and found that it had the cookie in it (thanks to @tin's link) and i was trying to set the cookie i received. It doesn't work for now but i guess i must have to send it to the client.